# how to make two html pages into one? with header and footer

Tags: java, html, merge

I want a `html` with `header` and `footer` in every page, while the main `html` `content` and the `header` , `footer` are separate two files, is there a decent way to merge these two files ? so that when I change the `header` or `footer`, there is no need to modify then main `content` `html` page.

Comment: use jsp and jstl if you using java

Answer (score 0):

In order to merge the two pages into a single file, you can use the JSoup library for Java. JSoup is an HTML parser which can handle these kind of operations easily.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, do you mean that I merge the two files by reading html node by node?

Comment: and when I use jsoup to parse the html, however it removes my img end tag, which leads erroer occurs when using ItextRender to transfer the html into pdf